# Error coming while integrating NLTK with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, nltk

I'm trying to integrate NLTK with Hadoop. Basically I want to pos_tag the words. I tried the following link:
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2008/11/sending-files-to-remote-task-nodes-with-hadoop-mapreduce/

But, while running the MapReduce program, I'm still getting the error:

```
14/12/09 11:45:53 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201412091132_0004_m_000000
14/12/09 11:45:53 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
Streaming Command Failed!
```

My Mapper program is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import re
#import sys
import zipimport

importer = zipimport.zipimporter('nltkandyaml.mod')
yaml = importer.load_module('yaml')
nltk = importer.load_module('nltk')


# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
for line in sys.stdin:

  line = line.strip()

  words = line.split()

  for word in words:

    a=nltk.pos_tag(word)
    print '%s\t%s' % (word, 1)
```

I'm using the same Reducer program as in word count example. I'm new to Hadoop. Please help.